# How to invoke shell script while staying in interactive mode

Tags: shell, c, exec

When I call:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", (void *) NULL);
```

The /bin/sh/ program is started, which opens a shell in which I can type commands. However, if I call:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "~/somescript.sh", (char *) 0 );
```

The /bin/sh program is also started and runs the given shell script but then closes afterwards.

Why doesn't the shell stay open after running a shell script? Is there anyway to keep it open after running the script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This is a normal shell behaviour that doesn't have anything in common with the fact that you run it from C - it happens even if you run the shell with the script from command line:

```
$ sh ~/somescript.sh
```

It might be difficult to force shell to stay in interactive mode after that. I found only the `--rcfile [file]` option to do that:

> Execute  commands  from  file  instead of the system wide
>   initialization file `/etc/bash.bashrc` and the standard personal
>   initialization file `~/.bashrc` if the shell is interactive (see
>   INVOCATION below).

I.e. you would do

```
$ sh --rcfile ~/somescript.sh
```

But your system rc files like `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` will not be run in this case.

Answer (score -1):

How about running an interactive shell at the end of your script?

```
#!/bin/sh

echo STUFF
echo MORE STUFF
sh
```